# jquery, finding a string then add a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to find a string then add a link to it. example:

```
<h1>you can Contact us</h1>
```

this is what i tried but it's not working.

```
$("h1:contains(Contact)").attr('href','test.yahoo.com');
```

also tried this one

```
$("h1:contains('Contact')").attr('href','test.yahoo.com');
```

what i want

you can [Contact](http://test.yahoo.com) us

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```js
$("h1:contains('Contact')").html(function(i, current) {
  return current.replace(/(Contact)/, '<a href="http://test.yahoo.com">$1</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>you can Contact us</h1>
```

---

But why not change the html directly ?

Comment: thanks, will try that. sorry i can't change directly ,the html is a plugin from django cms. "maybe my team leader can" anyway. thank you so much ^-^

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works in that it sets the attr on the h1 element.  Problem is h1 tags are not designed to be links.  You need to nest an a tag with the link inside the h1 tag.

`